# URDF_model_for_Create 2

Tags: ros, irobot-create

Can someone has the URDF model for the Create 2.0 from iRobot, I need to simulate at Gazebo the robot and simulate the laserscan with the robot, I would like to know if someone know about something of this for ROS.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but the create_robot/create_autonomy package has various URDFs for the Create here: https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_robot/tree/melodic/create_description/urdf